# How can I move and consolidate data in a Google Form responses sheet without altering the form's field order?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form that collects responses, and the data is stored in a Google Sheets document. I want to reorganize and consolidate the data in the responses sheet without changing the order and arrangement of the input fields in the Google Form.

Specifically, I want to move data from one column (column F) to another column (column B) without affecting the form's field order. This means that both the previously collected data and the future responses for that field should be stored in column B.

I have tried manually moving the column, but the issue is that the rest of the data is still stored in column F instead of column B.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this data reorganization in Google Sheets, ensuring that the form's field order remains intact?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this task. Thank you!

Comment: your sample has no data in column F. so either add sample data to match your description of the problem, or modify your description to suit the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new sheet try:

```
={'Form Responses 1'!A:A,'Form Responses 1'!C:F}
```

OR even:

```
={'Form Responses 1'!A:A,'Form Responses 1'!F:F,'Form Responses 1'!C:E}
```

**One single formula.**

Comment: Thanks. It is a good idea, but I am looking for a direct idea in order to be done on the main response sheet instead of creating another sheet.

Comment: Cannot be done. Not unless one uses scripts. But in any case, It is a bad idea messing with the original sheet. FWI. When one says *"new sheet"*, it means *"new tab"* (as you already have in your answer sheet).

Comment: No, the new sheet was created by one of the other users who was working on the shared sheet :)